# DataTables Requested Unknown Parameter

Tags: datatables

I've already researched everything I can.  I still get the dreaded error

`Requested the unknown parameter 'title' for row 0, column 0`

for the following code embedded in my index.html:

```
$("#cd-table").DataTable({
  "render": { "_": "plain", "filter": "filter", "display": "display"},
  "ajax" : { "url" : "cdsort.php", "dataSrc" : "array1" },
  "columns" : [ { "data": "title" }, { "data": "description" }, { "data": "location" }, { "data": "date" } ]
});
```

The server JSON response should be correct (undecoded):

```
{"array1":["  {\"title\":\"test\",\"description\":\"test\",\"location\":\"test\",\"date\":\"05\\\/Oct\\\/2016\"}"]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does using `{ "data": 0 }, { "data": 1}` etc. work?

Comment: I've tried that before.  All that does, apparently, is select the individual characters in the JSON string: 0 is '{', 1 is ", 2 is 'd'...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem.  It's a VERY subtle PHP mistake (to me).

While assembling my array of JSON objects, I was using this statement (in a `for` loop):

```
array_push($cd_json, json_encode(array("title" => $cd_row[0], "description" => $cd_row[1], "location" => $cd_row[2], "date" => $date_time)));
```

And later, when returning my JSON array to the client, I was using this:

```
echo json_encode(array("data" => $cd_json));
```

The mistake was using json_encode on top of a previous json_encode, effectively corrupting the JSON data type of my array.

When I do this instead, DataTables understands my data, and it's formatted correctly:

```
array_push($cd_json, array("title" => $cd_row[0], "description" => $cd_row[1], "location" => $cd_row[2], "date" => $date_time));

echo json_encode(array("data" => $cd_json));
```

Lesson learned: Just use one json_encode() call, and it will recursively encode arrays inside arrays.